# Custom Membership Provider with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, membership-provider

I am trying to implement a custom membership provider in ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Enitty Framework. For the user data I created a User class that holds all the login data plus some more.
When I tried to implement the MembershipProvider, some methods appeared that I need to implement which have a MembershipUser parameter in the signature:

```
public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
```

I know I can make my User class inherit the MembershipUser class and this won't be a problem. But when I tried to make it inherit, I couldn't set values for the readonly properties, like Email and others.

Is there any way that these methods can accept an object of type User? Or maybe there is some other better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

### References

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152065.aspx

[Custom MembershipUser with only needed parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303012/custom-membershipuser-with-only-needed-parameters)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

### Answer

You can create instances of MembershipUser and pass the properties (readonly or not) on the constructor, and then return that MembershipUser instance.

The documentation for the [MembershipUser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152065.aspx) has a quote that helped me to understand this better:

> Creating a new MembershipUser object does not add a new membership
>   user object to the membership data store.

If adding the custom properties is important that will require you to subclass MembershipUser.

For an example see: [Custom MembershipUser with only needed parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303012/custom-membershipuser-with-only-needed-parameters)

The last reference link shows a nice article with a [custom membership provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) using Linq-to-Sql rather than EF but the similarities are many.

Hope that helps.